# What do I end up with the same process ID when using bash file redirection

Tags: bash, io-redirection

In bash (typing in terminal), I execute the following simple command:

```
cat file1 > file2
```

it correctly creates file2 with the contents of file1. When I use eBPF (in this case Sysmon for Linux) to analyze what is happening under the covers I end up with bash and cat having the same PID. I have tried using strace to see what could be happening but there is still nothing that helps explain the PID behavior.

When I execute the above cat command I can see the following events being fired using Sysmon for Linux (which in turn uses eBPF).

1. Process creation of cat with process ID of 1234. This makes perfect sense as bash creates (in some fashion) a new process executing cat.
2. A file creation of file2 that originates from a process that is named bash (this makes sense since bash likely has some to do with the redirection). What doesn't make sense is that the same file creation, reports the pid of the process doing the file creation as 1234 which is the same PID as the cat command in (1) above.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how/why I end up with a file create with the same PID as the cat command?

Comment: As an optimization, the last command in a script is executing by calling `exec()` without first calling `fork()`, since the shell doesn't need to do anything after the command finishes.

Comment: "In bash" - is this a script or something you're typing into your terminal?

Comment: Typing in terminal (edit post)

Comment: The creation happens after the `fork()` that spawns the subshell that will later be replaced with `cat`, and before the `exec()` that actually replaces the subshell with a copy of `/bin/cat`. That's an implementation detail, though, not contractually guaranteed, so you shouldn't assume it (and for that reason, I don't like documenting it at all; better to document only things that are guaranteed to remain true, and to write code that depends only on things that are documented; to document an implementation detail is to tempt people to write code that breaks if it changes).

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in the POSIX specification prohibits a shell from performing redirections between the `fork()` and `execv*()` steps of starting an external process, and there are some compelling reasons a shell's author might choose to do this.

- Performing redirections post-fork in a subshell that's going to terminate itself via an exec() call means that there's no need to clean up the file descriptors in the parent shell.
- Performing redirections post-fork in a subshell that's going to terminate itself via an exec() call also simplifies error handling, because the parent can handle a redirection failure in the same way it would handle any other failure, either of the exec call itself or of the child process after it's executed; no separate codepaths required.

**But this is a shell implementation detail and subject to change; code that assumes one way or another** (or that assumes that a shell that performs its redirections post-fork in *one* use case will do so in *all* use cases) **is inherently fragile and should not be written.**